# Return the last six months of a current date (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, type-conversion

Good afternoon.

I would like to get a list of the last six months before the current date.

Example.

```
Current Date -> 10/02/2020
```

Format of output pretended in the select Oracle Query:

```
02-2020 -> (Current)
01-2020
12-2019
11-2019
10-2019
09-2019
```

Best regards and many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `connect by`:

```
select to_char(add_months(sysdate, -level + 1), 'mm-yyyy') mth from dual connect by level <= 6
```

Comment: How can I order in an ascending way. First old dates to recent. I can´t figure how to use AS to order by column name

Comment: Add `order by mth` at the end, like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f1558570918194f4ccec7b7538d51234).

Comment: @PonderStibbons: the problem is that `mth` is a character string, not a date, so the results come out as `01-2020, 02-2020, 09-2019, 10-2019, 11-2019, 12-2019` because it's effectively sorting by the month first, then the year. If `MTH` was formatted as 'YYYY-MM' it would work as expected.

Comment: @PedroEstevesAntunes - please read BobJarvis' note, sort data by level descending.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your subquestion about ordering - to order anything in SQL you need to use an ORDER BY clause. In this case you can't order the formatted dates easily, but you can use the LEVEL value generated by the `CONNECT BY`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 1 - LEVEL), 'MM-YYYY')
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6
  ORDER BY LEVEL DESC
```